# Make value of a key which is an immutable object have multiple references so that they can be altered by any of those references

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap, recursive-query

I'm looking for a way to use Python Dictionary such that I have the reference to the value of the dictionary.

I'm looking for a way to assign, the value of key `0` to value of key `1` such that if I change the value of key `1`, the value of key `0` will also change to that of value of key `1`. BUT, the value of key `1` won't change with changes in value of key `0`. Here's a demonstration of the behavior I want:

```
d = dict()
d[0] = 0
d[1] = 1
d[2] = 2
print(d[0], d[1], d[2])
d[2] = d[1]
print(d[0], d[1], d[2])
d[1] = d[0]
print(d[0], d[1], d[2])
d[0] = 3
print(d[0], d[1], d[2])
```

should print:

```
0 1 2
0 1 1
0 0 0
3 3 3
```

However, it prints:

```
0, 1, 2
0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0
3, 0, 1
```

The code I've written below does what I want:

```
class Recursive_Dict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = dict()

    def get_val(self, key):
        is_ptr = self.d[key][0]
        val = self.get_val(self.d[key][1]) if is_ptr else self.d[key][1]
        return val

    def set_val(self, key, val, p=False):
        self.d[key] = [p, val]

d = Recursive_Dict()

d.set_val(0, 0)
d.set_val(1, 1)
d.set_val(2, 2)
print(d.get_val(0), d.get_val(1), d.get_val(2))
d.set_val(2, 1, p=True)
print(d.get_val(0), d.get_val(1), d.get_val(2))
d.set_val(1, 0, p=True)
print(d.get_val(0), d.get_val(1), d.get_val(2))
d.set_val(0, 3)
print(d.get_val(0), d.get_val(1), d.get_val(2))
```

Is there a better, perhaps built in way to do this?

Comment: Can we ask *why* you're doing this? This feels like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040); most "derived value" scenarios like this are best handled with a class using `@property`s that make specific values computed in terms of other values (or for a more general handler, using `__getattr__` as a "property for any undefined attribute").

Comment: As for making it cleaner, using `__getitem__` to allow normal lookups, and `__setitem__` (for the cases where `p` is `False`) would make normal usage look normal, so `set_val` would only need to be involved for abnormal usage. Implementing `collection.abc.MutableMapping` completely would make it a much more useful replacement for `dict`.

Comment: Just wrap your dictionary values in a mutable type, something like `class DictEntry: ...`

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat relevant but not EXACTLY what you want.

You will need something that is MUTABLE as a value to your key.
`1` is an integer and is IMMUTABLE, put it in a list `[1]`
and then it is MUTABLE (or changeable) and you can use it as value!

```
a = [0]
b = [1]
c = [2]

a = b = c

d = {0: a, 1: b, 2: c} #Mutable objects are now values to the dictionary
print(d)
```

Gives:

```
{0: [2], 1: [2], 3: [2]}
```

Now if we do something like:

```
a.pop()
a.append(5)
print(d)
```

would now give:

```
{0: [5], 1: [5], 3: [5]} #Since a = b = c
```

You can now even change the values using `b` or `c`. But just remember. pop() and then append(). Do not do `b = [new_val]`, instead do `b.pop()` and then `b.append(new_val)` and watch the changes propogate to values of keys `0` and `3`

So in our case, if you want to propogate a change of the first value in the `list` alone, then pop the elements and append a new element.

So let's say you want value of the key `3` to change from `[2]`, to `[3]`

Because we did `a = b = c` They all point to the same list. If you CHANGE the list, then the changes will propogate to the values! But if you reassign the variables `a`, `b` or `c` to a NEW list, you are REASSIGNING `a` to something new, and killing the old link if that makes sense.